# Monte Carlo - Uniform Distribution

Tags: r, random, montecarlo

I have this problem:

> Each week the three gas stations near your home sell at a price per gallon of X1, X2 and X3,
>   respectively, where Xi are IID uniform random variables on [3.80, 4.20]. You purchase gas at
>   the station with the lowest price. Use simple Monte Carlo methods to estimate average price
>   per gallon of gas that you will pay, with the estimation error no larger than $0.05.

Can someone post an R code for this kind of problem or tell me how to approach this ?

Answer (score 2):

Sure

Lets start with sampling

```
set.seed(12345)

n <- 1000
stationA <- runif(n, min=3.80, max=4.20)
stationB <- runif(n, min=3.80, max=4.20)
stationC <- runif(n, min=3.80, max=4.20)

whatIpay <- pmin(stationA, stationB, stationC)
avgIpay  <- mean(whatIpay)
stdIpay  <- sd(whatIpay)
```

now you have to figure out what value of `n` you need to get within desired error